# TCL script generator for NS2

Tags: networking, tcl, ns2

Is there an open source TCL script generator for [NS2](http://isi.edu/nsnam/ns/)? There is NAM that comes with NS2. Is there anything else. A web based one would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general Tcl script generator? That's quite tricky, as Tcl's really a general programming language. But if you're interested in just generating simple programs, it's not that hard. A Tcl command is a sequence of words separated by spaces and terminated by a newline character. Where you've got characters that are Tcl's [metacharacters](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), you can quote them by putting a backslash in front (except for newline; replace that with `\n` instead). Anything more complicated than a simple call can probably be relegated to a procedure, but I doubt you need anything particularly complex for NS2 scripts.

If you want something pre-written, there's [NSG](http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.com/2009/10/tcl-script-generator.html) but I don't know very much about it. It's Java, not web-based.

Answer (score 3):

**NSG** is a good TCL code generator that is free. Check out

https://sites.google.com/site/pengjungwu/nsg

You may also want to check out **mannasim**

http://www.mannasim.dcc.ufmg.br/

Comment: java based and simple with 253 kb. iheard that it will not generate agents. and we must add them ourself

Answer (score 0):

This operation system is user-friendly to criation of the TCL scripts.

There also several tools includes him. Mannasim, Castalia, OMNET++...

Look: http://sourceforge.net/projects/liowsn/